# Automatic AngularJS expression value in form submission via GET request

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a web app written in angularjs that I want to send respective values from individual pages to a server via a GET request but I'm having it done automatically when the page loads.

A snippet of my code is below:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function loaded(){
        document.getElementById("dataSubmit").submit();
    }
</script>

<form id="dataSubmit" action="http://127.0.0.1" method="get" target="submission.frame">
    <input name="data" type="hidden" value={{myData}}>
    <input type="submit" id="subbut" value="submit">
    <iframe name="submission.frame" hidden></iframe>
</form>
<script>
    window.onload = loaded();
</script>
```

My code above automatically sends the input data named "data" with value {{myData}} which, depends on what page the user is on, to the ip 127.0.0.1 and a script runs at that end and writes the data to a text file.

The problem is that when I try to pass the Angularjs expression {{myData}}, instead of passing the data fetched automatically when the page is loaded, it sends a string literal "{{myData}}" and writes that to the file at the other end.

However, when I click the 'submit' button that I've added to the form, the data sends perfectly and the value that I wanted is written to the file.
I tried using an onload function so that the submission only occurs after the page has loaded so the expression has had time to evaluate but still no luck.

For those wondering, my iframe tag makes it so that the submission form is invisible so when the submission occurs it does not redirect the user to the IP that the data is being sent to.

To clarify the problem, the angular expression {{myData}} is not being evaluated when the form is submitted upon page load, but when the submit button is clicked, {{myData}} evaluates and the value is sent. I need the value of {{myData}} to be submitted in the form when the page loads.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are facing is a pretty normal behavior, of course the page is finished loading but Angular didn't have time to evaluate the template interpolations.

To be honest I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with that automated form submition, you can just use the $http service to send the data to whatever end-point you want. This way you know exactly when you have the data attached to the variables.

Tho if for some REALLY weird reason you still want to do the normal javascript form submition you need to create a directive in which you will include the $window service and add scome code looking like:

```
var autoSubmit = function () {
    $scope.$watch("myDataVariable", function (newVal) {
        if (newVal) {form.submit()}
    })
}
$window.bind("onload", autoSubmit);
```

The code is not tested, it's a sample of how I would do it ... well I won't do something like that but you know what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
What I'm trying to achieve is make a log of what pages are viewed. How long does Angular need in order to evaluate? I've tried giving my auto-submit a delay before executing...

Comment: That would be an easy way to do it but a very unaccurate way. There's no specific time, it dpeneds on the client machine, you could add a delay of 5, 10 seconds but maybe the user will leave the page before that gets triggered. Why don't you use google analytics ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Is there a way to perform a GET request in angular without using $http module service since I have other services which deal with a database from which data will be sent when the user visits the correct page which means that I will probably have to implement the exact same protocol but the data changes when the user makes a request for a certain page.

Comment: You can create a custom service "vistPage" that uses the $http service to make the GET request and in your controller you would call it something like visitPage("register.html); or w/e parameters you need to pass.